# Joomla 1.5 main menu adding extra subdirectory

Tags: php, content-management-system, menu, joomla

I am having trouble with my main menu in Joomla. I have the installation on a testing site in a subdirectory that I am accessing via ip address (ex. http://255.255.255.255/joomla)

For some reason all the menu links except for 'Home' add an extra subdirectory that isnt there. for example, I have 'contact' link, the menu links to http://255.255.255.255/joomla/joomla/menu-id-85.html which in turn links to 404.

Whats going on here? fyi I have the configuration file set to:

```
var $live_site = 'http://255.255.255.255/joomla';
```

the site is running on iis7 with several other successful joomla production sites running.

UPDATE: I have removed the $live_site variable and still no luck! any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Do you really need $live_site? I've had Joomla installations in subdirectories without it.

Comment: it's not needed. I just commented it out but no change. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what your problem is. Try turning off SEF URLs and see if the links work. If so, you probably need to take a look at your HTACCESS file and change the RewriteBase or comment it out completely.